# I am converting my Json data to .CSV format using Jq but unable to run it

Tags: json, csv, jq

**Input :-**

```
 {"Timestamp":140,
  "DateTime":"2014-06-02 14:32:34.440 PDT",
  "CustomerId":"01",
  "VisitorId":"78"}
```

**Desired Output**

```
Timestamp; DateTime;  CustomerId; VisitorId
140;       2014-06-02 14:32:34.440 PDT; 01; 78
```

**I tried the following code**:-

```
results.txt
| (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols
| map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows
| $cols, $rows[] | @csv
```

**Error:-**
'add' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I don't know what is wrong. I am using window platform with cygwin.

Comment: 1) Example input; 2) desired output; 3) what have you tried? Reread your post: How is anybody supposed to help you here?

Answer (score 1):

With your input, and the following program in tocsv.jq:

```
(keys_unsorted | join(",")),
([.[]] | @csv)
```

the command:

```
$ jq -r -f tocsv.jq input.json
```

produces:

```
Timestamp,DateTime,CustomerId,VisitorId
140,"2014-06-02 14:32:34.440 PDT","01","78"
```

Eliminating the quotation marks in the second line is left as an exercise for the interested reader :-)  [Hint: use `join(",")` again.]

WARNING: the above program is intended only for jq version 1.5 or later. When using an earlier version of jq, using `to_entries` or explicitly specifying the key names may be required.